# Start using github - which folder do I git init?

Tags: github

I just started developing and created a local folder structure like this based on what I've seen:

```
~/go/src/github.com/my_git_name/my_app1/....project files
~/go/src/github.com/my_git_name/my_app2/....project files
```

I just learned how to make use of `git` and want to start repos for each of my projects and push what I have done locally to those project repos.

1. Which directory do I `git init` in? `~/go/src` to match the structure of `github` or `/go/src/github.com/mygitname` ? or somewhere else?
2. Can I push from local computer and automatically create the repos for the project names or do I have to create the repos on `github.com` first?

I've not been able to find an answer to this apart from running `git init` in the project directory but adding `github.com` to the folder structure has thrown me little bit...

cant find the solution online to this specific folder structure

Comment: You'd `git init` in `my_app1` and `my_app2` then these would each be individual repositories on github.com

Comment: thanks for clearing that up Tom...I thought having `gitub.com/username` in the structure was necessary to link it to my `github` account so if I didn't `git init` in there thing might not have linked up....

Answer (score 0):

See Tom's comment/answer...

`git init` in each project you want to push to `github.com`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).